# How to select element which doesn't has Id attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have two textarea and one of them has `id` attribute and other one doesn't has. Something like this:

```
<textarea> </textarea>
<textarea id = 'idname'> </textarea>
```

Now I need to select first textarea, How can I do that?

Comment: `$('textarea:first')` ?

Comment: @AlexK. Your solution is right, but just in this case .. In reality that textarea isn't always the first one.

Comment: Who flagged my question as "too board"? May please and please tell me my question is too board from what perspective?

Comment: Ignore it, its not too broad at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could combine the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and the `[id]` [attribute selector](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg_7LM4bjKAhUjyYMKHQsZAZAQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2FAttribute_selectors&usg=AFQjCNFZpPa7yYepjOspiXgpYBUjFA7csQ&sig2=09nnvwQmFKVnU7oHMaqFvw) in order to negate elements with an `id` attribute:

```
textarea:not([id]) {}
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('textarea:not([id])');
```

```
$('textarea:not([id])');
```

Basic Example:

```css
textarea:not([id]) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea id='idname'></textarea>
```

Comment: Just for more information, may you please tell me how can I select an textarea which has specific attribute? like `name`

Comment: @stack `textarea[name]` or `textarea[name="value"]`.

Answer (score 3):

As you also don't mind a jQuery answer:

```
$('textarea:not([id])');
```

or

```
$('textarea').not('[id]');
```

Update:

For a specific name:

```
$('textarea[name="somename"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following in your case:

```
$('textarea:not(#idname)')[0]
```

Selector depends on exact requirements and mark-up

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery solution :**

Using **[:not() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** :

```
$('textarea:not(#idname)')
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
 $('textarea:not(#idname)').text('selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea> </textarea>
<textarea id='idname'> </textarea>
```

Comment: Probably the `#`. That would try to select an `id="id"` element.

Comment: No, that answer is different... they want to check here if it *has an id*. You are checking if the id is id. We should really be asking why you just got an upvote as this is incorrect?

Comment: Your answer is now "correct", just *not for this question*. They want to know an element that *has no id attribute*.

Comment: @stack... very polite of you, but this answer is incorrect. Bad enough that correct answers get downvoted, but upvoting incorrect ones is just as bad :)